# How to pass a query param from controller to service in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form, where in i submit a text using ng-click, now it calls a rest service and insert into the DB - working fine. at the same time, in same function, it calls another rest service but nothing is happening , i want to know how can I pass parameter to service???

Controller.js

```
                app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'PostFactory', '$location', function ($scope, PostFactory, $location) {

                /* callback for ng-click 'createUser': */
                $scope.createPost = function () {
                    alert("in createPost" + $scope.UserPost.postText);
                    alert("in createPost" + $scope.UserPost);
                    PostFactory.postmain.create($scope.UserPost)
                    $scope.allposts.push($scope.UserPost);
                    $scope.UserPost = "";
                    $scope.allresultsfinal = PostFactory.allresults.query({tag: $scope.UserPost.postText})
                    $location.path('/view1');
                }

                $scope.allposts = PostFactory.postmain.query();


                /*UserFactory.get({}, function (userFactory) {
                 $scope.firstname = userFactory.firstName;
                 })*/
            }]);
```

Services.js

```
            'use strict';

            /* Services */

            var services = angular.module('ngdemo.services', ['ngResource']);
            //alert("In services");
            services.factory('PostFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
                return  {

                    postmain: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts', {}, {
                        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true },
                        create: {method: 'POST'}
                    }),
                    allresults: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/result/:tag', {id: '@id'}, {
                        query: {method: 'GET', params: {id: '@id'}, isArray: true },
                        create: {method: 'POST'}
                    })};
            }]);
```

in allresults, id is not coming or I dont know if controll is reaching here or not. post submission in "postmain" and query is working fine. please let me know how to do it?

I need to send "tag" which is "#scope.UserPost.postText" as param in controller

```
$scope.allresultsfinal = PostFactory.allresults.query({tag: $scope.UserPost.postText})
```

to service.js "allresults" and get the data back from rest service.

Comment: Do you mean you wan the URL to be formed as "/ngdemo/web/posts/result/:tag?id=someValue", if so what is the value of id

Comment: Sorry, its not id, its tag, instead of id, it shud be tag

Comment: url shud be /ngdemo/web/posts/result/:tag where tag is the string which i will be sending thru query param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below,

```
allresults: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/result/:tag', {}, {
     query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true },
     create: {method: 'POST'}
})};
```

In controller

```
$scope.allresultsfinal = PostFactory.allresults.query({tag: $scope.UserPost.postText})
```

Comment: Didnt work! My controller code is, is there a problem???? --  @RequestMapping(value = "/result/{tag}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    List<Place> results(@PathVariable("tag") String tag) {
        List<Place> places = null;
        System.out.println("tag : " + tag);
        try {

Comment: Shouldnt be the prob with controller, because it works independently, tag value is not reaching controller

Comment: I could see the following line in your code                         $scope.allposts.push($scope.UserPost);                      
$scope.UserPost = "";  // You are making this object blank           
PostFactory.allresults.query({tag: $scope.UserPost.postText})// How do you expect to get the object here?

Answer (score 2):

Anything you pass to the service function that isnt explicitly specified is just always added as a query param, so you should just need to do something like:

```
allresults: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/result/:tag', {tag: '@tag'}, {  
`query: {method: 'GET',   
`params: {},   
`isArray: true },  
`create: {method: 'POST'}  
})};
```

Then call it like this

```
$scope.allresultsfinal = PostFactory.allresults.query(  
`{tag: $scope.UserPost.postText,  
`id:$scope.someId}//perhaps $routeParams.id ??  
`);
```

Comment: No, it didnt work,    allresults: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/result/:tag', {tag: '@tag'}, {
            query: {method: 'GET', params: {tag: '@tag'}, isArray: true },
            create: {method: 'POST'}
        })}; and controller -- $scope.allresultsfinal = PostFactory.allresults.query({tag: $scope.UserPost.postText})